# SnackBar Direction in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar, android-layout-direction

I implement user interface in Jetpack Compose, and **want to show SnackBar inside Compose functions**.

**the issue is that i can't change SnackBar's Layout Direction to Rtl.**

What I've implemented to change the direction:

```
LaunchedEffect(SnackbarHost(hostState = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState, snackbar = {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
        Snackbar(it)
    }
}
)) {

    viewModel.snackBarMessage.collect {
        scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
            it,
            null,
            SnackbarDuration.Short
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a screen of the expected result?

Comment: it's not complicated, simply mirror the layout, thus action button is on the left , and the message on the right of layout(text direction is also rtl)

Answer (score 0):

you should insert your scaffold in CompositionLocalProvider scope.
like this:

```
 CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
     
Scaffold(){
...
}

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).